# How to limit data in a single cell of DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have `DataTable` version 1.10.12 and I want to display only images in one cell of particular row. There are many images in database but I only want to show 2 images.

How can I achieve this?
How to set limit in `forEach` loop?

This is my code:

```
{
    data: 'plays', name: 'plays', "defaultContent": "",
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        var plays = '';
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            plays += '<img class="img" src="/images/theme/image_placeholder.jpg" alt="">'
        })
        return plays;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The forEach method has an aditional parameter that gives you the iteration index:

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
   // Your code
}[, thisArg]);
```

So you can simply check if index is greater than 1 to have only 2 iterations:

```
data.forEach(function (item, index) {

        // Add this
        if (index > 1) {
            return;
        }

        plays += '<img class="img" src="/images/theme/image_placeholder.jpg" alt="">'
    })
```